# PHP fopen() over HTTP, how can i check if exists and its MIME?

Tags: php, file, csv, mime-types, fopen

Im' trying to parse a CSV remotely from my script. I open it with `fopen()` and then parse the data with `fgetcsv`. I need to check if file actually exists. This will not work, always returns `true`:

```
    $response->setStatusCode(500);
    $response->setContent($url);
    if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) == FALSE) return $response;
```

The problem is, even if the resource doesn't exist, my ISP will redirect me to its search page (i'm developing locally).

It will be fine just to check the MIME of the url, if possible. Any help?

Comment: Try making just a HEAD request with `get_headers`: http://php.net/get_headers.  You should be able to see if the resource is available from the status code there.

Comment: Try this -> if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) return $response;

Comment: @mellamokb it sounds a good solution, it returns 302! Thanks.. i would mark it as an answer.

Comment: Get the URI then check it ends -> example.com/file.csv ->   
$file = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];   
echo system("file -i -b ".$file);

Comment: @Gremo: Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making just a HEAD request with [get_headers](http://php.net/get_headers). You should be able to see if the resource is available from the status code there.

Comment: The approach is easy and works fine checking status and content-type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set other DNS-Servers in your local machines network configuration. For example you can use Googles DNS-Servers (http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns).

Comment: I already use google dns servers (8.8.8.8) but for some strange reason i still see ISP search page. Any clue?

Comment: ... and switch ISPs. An ISP that does dns redirection like that, with no way to opt out, should be driven into bankruptcy.

Comment: @Gremo: deep packet inspection, most likely.

Comment: @MarcB yeah i know, it's a bad thing. But now i have to focus on the problem rather than changing ISP :)

Answer (score -1):

**The solution:** Disable the redirection. Usually this involves changing DNS servers to those *not* managed by your ISP.

**The workaround:** Call `stream_get_meta_data()` on the resource returned by `fopen()`. In case of `http:` protocol, the returned array will have a `wrapper_data` item containing all HTTP response headers. Note that if redirects are involved, *all* responses will be in the same array, as in the example below.

```
$ php -r '$a = fopen("http://www.google.com/", "r"); print_r(stream_get_meta_data($a));'
Array
(
    [wrapper_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => HTTP/1.0 302 Found
            [1] => Location: http://www.google.co.uk/
            [2] => Cache-Control: private
            [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [4] => Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=5e6e2f87c95ce139:FF=0:TM=1317669253:LM=1317669253:S=uaGlatRCh9XB8oAI; expires=Wed, 02-Oct-2013 19:14:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
            [5] => Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2011 19:14:13 GMT
            [6] => Server: gws
            [7] => Content-Length: 221
            [8] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
            [9] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
            [10] => Date: Mon, 03 Oct 2011 19:14:13 GMT
            [11] => Expires: -1
            [12] => Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
            [13] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
            [14] => Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=9c5c0212c24c4ca1:FF=0:TM=1317669253:LM=1317669254:S=P7nzy5lBsmvuZm8A; expires=Wed, 02-Oct-2013 19:14:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk
            [15] => Set-Cookie: NID=51=J8T2rxPOdsbfWlIWhWIdL4uerFqLibBV2LDh81OdqmfvRvq3zXwAJ7tsNEmBby_h2wT4Qv8Wd7QK6CyG-leo9mgR4RbFeNpw83mMGlvCHhU0uiUv6ki2doinv1EBU5XM; expires=Tue, 03-Apr-2012 19:14:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk; HttpOnly
            [16] => Server: gws
            [17] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
        )

    [wrapper_type] => http
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r
    [unread_bytes] => 4096
    [seekable] =>
    [uri] => http://www.google.com/
    [timed_out] =>
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
)
```